# Set parent with automatic weight error

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, bones, parent

So I have [this](https://sketchfab.com/models/a95bb0267ce94866a9c141bbde2baa77) Blender model:-



I tried  using ctrl P -> set parent with automatic weight. It shows an error code saying:

> "bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones"

What can I do? Do check the blender file to check the my mistake(s).

Comment: Bone heat weighting can fail from non-manifold geometry (but borders are acceptable), degenerate edges, degenerate verts, bones not contained fully within the mesh.  Limit your mesh by halves and autoweight each subpart to localize the problem.  Your download requires registration so I didn't take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two armatures parented to that mesh.

Delete these two armatures and you will bring back your full menu.

See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

that will happen sometimes and there is no solution but to add weights yourself. you could try with envolope weights too, but that wont always work either. you could try checking your scale rotation and location too. they should be at 0 0 0 for rotation and location, and 1 1 1 for scale. Also looking at your model, you have some complex things like the finger blasters, and I may be wrong, but it also looks really high poly, so that may be an issue.